# Code in for-loops vs if-else statements

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, time

I was trying to solve this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/

The following code passed all tests in 44 ms.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if (!mp.containsKey(s.charAt(i))){
            mp.put(s.charAt(i), i);
            //max = Math.max(max, i-first+1);
        }
        else {
            if (mp.get(s.charAt(i))+1>=first){
                first = mp.get(s.charAt(i))+1;
            }
            mp.put(s.charAt(i), i);
            //max = Math.max(max, i-first+1);
        }
        max = Math.max(max, i-first+1);
    }
```

But the following code passed all tests in only 20 ms.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if (!mp.containsKey(s.charAt(i))){
            mp.put(s.charAt(i), i);
            max = Math.max(max, i-first+1);
        }
        else {
            if (mp.get(s.charAt(i))+1>=first){
                first = mp.get(s.charAt(i))+1;
            }
            mp.put(s.charAt(i), i);
            max = Math.max(max, i-first+1);
        }
    }
```

Why is there such a significant difference? The max value is changed only once in both of the samples but changing it in the if-else statements is far more efficient than changing it at the end of the for loop. Is this an exception or should we follow this standard whenever coding?

Comment: It's hard to predict exactly what the effects of that transformation would be on the machine code. Maybe it ended up organizing its jumps differently? Can you dump the assembly code?

Comment: is this the time from the website where you put the code? Maybe it is a delay of their interpreter? You should check this on a local system with a local vm and a performance framework

Comment: It's highly unlikely that the two programs would perform differently... What you observe is probably related to how busy the server was when you submitted your code. You should test it in a controlled environment.

Comment: yeh that could be the case, I will test it in a controlled environment asap.

Comment: i tried testing using the time taken to execute the same string by the two different methods (i tried some really really long strings) but couldn't get any meaningful results

Answer (score 1):

On simplifying (not early optimizing, see max!) one gets

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char ch = s.charAt(i);
    Integer n = mp.get(ch):
    if (n != null) {
        first = Math.max(first, n + 1);
    }
    mp.put(ch, i);
    max = Math.max(max, i - first + 1);
}
```

Remark the double put of value i in the original version.
If the first Math.max is replaced with an if, the code might be faster.

It is hard to make a statement w.r.t. to speed here for the two original versions, maybe the hotspot compiler saw the redundancy. Or whatever.

It would be nice seeing a java 8 version, using `mp.putIfAbsent` or such, but that might meke it slower.

Comment: @Hulk thanks, `first` (maximizing with oneself) it should have been. Corrected. Hard to read.